# Process entire page with regex before sending back to client

Tags: php, regex, apache, wordpress

Is it possible to process an entire wordpress page (by page I mean the response to any requested url in the site) html with a regex before it gets sent to the client? Is this best achieved by the server rather than php, and how would it get done in apache?

Comment: do you want to change / replace something?

Comment: I want to wrap all ampersands in the html with a span and class in order to avoid doing the same with javascript on the client side... wouldn't've thought that merited a downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start output buffering on the beginning with `ob_start()`, at the end get the contents with `$content = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();`. You can then run regex on your content with `preg_replace` and then just `echo $content;`

### Example

```
ob_start();

echo "Hello World!";

$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

// Outputs "Hello StackOverflow!"
echo preg_replace("/World/", "StackOverflow", $content);
```